# Reverse Index en SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de ordenar alfabéticamente una columna pero la salida no es correcta. No sé en qué estoy fallando.

Primero creo dos tablas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE docs01 (id SERIAL, doc TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE invert01 (
  keyword TEXT,
  doc_id INTEGER REFERENCES docs01(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Luego le ingreso unos datos a la tabla *docs01*:

```sql
INSERT INTO docs01 (doc) VALUES
('gas station turn left and go one mile and the restaurant is a red'),
('building on your left Your friend is very late and calls you to'),
('tell you that they are on a farm and walking around behind a barn'),
('with no sign of a restaurant Then you say did you turn left or'),
('right at the gas station and they say I followed your directions'),
('perfectly I have them written down it says turn left and go one'),
('mile at the gas station Then you say I am very sorry because'),
('while my instructions were syntactically correct they sadly'),
('contained a small but undetected semantic error'),
('Again in all three types of errors Python is merely trying its hardest');
```

Y finalmente quiero llenar la tabla *invert01* con los datos de *docs01* pero de manera ordenada:

```sql
INSERT INTO invert01 (doc_id, keyword)                
SELECT DISTINCT id, s.keyword AS keyword 
FROM docs01 AS D, unnest(string_to_array(D.doc, ' ')) s(keyword) ORDER BY keyword, id;
```

Pero al ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```sql
SELECT keyword, doc_id FROM invert01 ORDER BY keyword, doc_id LIMIT 10;
```

Ocurre que la tabla aparece desordenada en la columna keyword
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que en el ORDER mayusculos y minusculos importan.